# Which cmdlet to use for creating a domain (folder) under a Primary Zone on the DNS-server?

Tags: powershell, dns, powershell-cmdlet

As the below picture shows, I want to use a PowerShell cmdlet to create/delete domains (folders) under a primary zone in the Windows DNS Server. I've have not been able to figure out which DNSServer cmdlet to use ref. [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/?view=win10-ps&viewFallbackFrom=winserver2016-ps)

As the picture below shows I have manually created "sandkasse.no" (sandbox), and added  using the GUI "dev.sandkasse.no", "prodfix.sandkasse.no" etc. But not yet figured out which cmdlet that will create yet another one for me.

Win 2016

[image]

Comment: You're just creating another (primary) zone there, so the cmdlet to use is [`Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone).

Comment: I know that it would do the trick, problem is that it is not up to me to decide, and the DNS config at my company is structured like that - primary domain mycorp.com, and then folders/domains as subdomains. Must admit that I do not know enough about DNS to say if the current is ok :-)

Comment: Explain what you want to create instead of pointing to a command option in a picture. If you want to create a domain use Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone. If you are creating a subdomain/resource_record (and not a zone) use the Add-DnsServerResourceRecord family of CmdLets. Example: `example.com` is a domain (zone). `www.example.com` is typically a subdomain (resource record) added to a domain (zone).

Comment: @JohnHanley - Better now?

Comment: Next question: What type of records (A, CNAME, TXT, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.
If you check your zone with the following command, you can see, that the records in the "New Domains" in the GUI are just shown as normal records with a "." in between (like sandkasse.no)

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "contoso.com"
```

Actually, if you just add a "DnsServerResourceRecord" like shown below with a Name "test.test" it will show up in the GUI like a "New Domain" (In my case I created a CNAME "test.test").

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecord -CName -Name "test.test" -HostNameAlias "Host34.lab.contoso.com" -ZoneName "Contoso.com"
```

##### Resources to lookup

[Add-DnsServerResourceRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/add-dnsserverresourcerecord?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-4-add-a-cname-resource-record)

[Get-DnsServerResourceRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/get-dnsserverresourcerecord?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

[German: administrator.de: Powershell DNS neue Domain anlegen](https://administrator.de/forum/powershell-dns-neue-domain-anlegen-473533.html)

["If you only create an empty domain (subdomain in your zone) with the GUI; the file is not updated! When you stop & start the DNS server, you'll even see that the empty domain is gone.
So that means that using 'New Domain..." from the GUI really doesn't do anything in your zone, until you add a record."](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5624ffbf-96dd-4d62-91f6-8bdcc264ef71/create-a-new-dns-domain-within-a-zone-using-script?forum=winserverDS)